# Using properties with NgClass directive

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, ng-class

Im trying to do something which seems like it should be fairly simple, however I can't find out how to do it and it doesnt seem to be in the docs. Here's a simple example:

```
<div *ngFor="let card of cards | async">
    <div [ngClass]="{card.color : true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Im able to do `[ngClass]="[card.color]"` or `[ngClass]="{'red' : true}"`

However, as soon as I try to combine the two I get the following error:`Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 6 in [{card.color: true}]`

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: so what's the problem with `[ngClass]="[card.color]"`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Sorry I should have been more clear, instead of `true` I have a dynamic variable which wont always be true

Comment: Do you mean `[ngClass]="condtion ? 'true-class' : 'false-class' "` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

directiveName - is the shorthand form for structural directives where the long form can only be applied to  tags. The short form implicitly wraps the element where it's applied in a .

[prop]="value" is for object binding to properties (@Input() of an Angular component or directive or a property of a DOM element).

When you are using `[ngClass]` what you can bind to it is an **expression**, in these cases, the common thing is using the **conditional operator**

here's the example:

```
var c = ((a < b) ? 'minor' : 'major');
```

The c variable will be `minor` if the value is true, and `major` if the value is false.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 ngClass={{card.color}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to set the class given by `card.color` conditionally:

```
[ngClass]="{card.color: condition}"
```

Comment: Yes, this is true